# Puzzling Projector Condundrum - Flickers and goes off when on a certain facebook page and nothing else

Tags: google-chrome, projector

Here's one that's a bit of a mind boggler, I'm just asking out of curiousity.

I have a computer hooked up to a projector. It works fine, in every single thing I've ever done, gaming, movies, etc. etc.

However, if I go to facebook, and go to my About tab, and scroll down the page, when I get to the 'Music' section, if I scroll down any further, my display starts freaking out (flickering, distorting lines) for a few seconds like the cable is a little loose, and then the projector goes blue (ie. no signal).

If I scroll back up, it returns to normal.

I have literally no idea what on earth could possibly cause this as it's clearly a hardware issue, but nothing else I have ever encountered triggers it, except for facebook's about page.

Can anyone think of any possible explanation just scientifically out of curiosity that could explain this?

Edit: This only occurs in Chrome

Comment: Is the projector hooked directly to the computer?

Comment: Yup, HDMI cable.